# Unable to use SPEmailEventReceiver

Tags: event-handlers, incoming-email

I'm attempting to create a `SPEmailEventReciever` on an Email enabled library...The problem is that intellisense is not showing that class for me, so I am unable to inherit from it.

MSDN shows it in the Microsoft.SharePoint workflow namespace, so it should show up with all of the other classes (such as SPItemEventReciever, etc).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx

Comment: Works ok for me. Are you creating your class from scratch or using the Visual Studio tools to Add new item > Event receiver > List Email Events etc

Comment: I just used the designer and selected List Email events...It auto-generated the class inheriting from SPEmailEventReceiver, except intellisense doesn't like the class name. It prevents me from building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the project and re-added it. It worked fine this time.

I'm wondering if it was because I accidentally selected 'Sandboxed Solution' when initially creating the project.

Answer (score 1):

For intellisense, There might be some problem with your VS templates for SharePoint.
Anyway, problem with intellisense will not stop you to inherit the class in code. Create a class like below :

```
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPEmailEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// The list received an e-mail message.
       /// </summary>
       public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData)
       {
           base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);
       }


    }
```

Ensure that you have reference for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll